# Где взять сборку Anaconda с Python 3.5.2?

Tags: python, установка, python-3.5, anaconda

Требуется установить TenserFlow на Python.
В данный момент на оф сайте Anaconda доступны версии 3.6 и 2.7. На оф сайте TenserFlow написано, что требуется по меньшей 3.5.x. Попробовал 3.6 - не пашет. Погуглил - советуют использовать стабильную 3.5.2.

Имеется экзешник для установки чистого Python 3.5.2, однако мне необходима Anaconda целиком, дабы кодить с удобствами в Spyder'e.

Вопрос - как получить такую сборку? Может быть, можно их как-то совместить? Если нет, откуда ее взять?

Comment: Почему не использовать уже готовый docker image? https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/

Comment: Можно установить Spyder отдельно, без anaconda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [архивом Anaconda](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/index.html)

Вам, скорее всего, нужна версия [4.3.0](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/old-pkg-lists/4.3.0/py35)

Comment: Да, спасибо. Уже нашел и хотел ответить сам.

Как минимум с версией Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64.exe (это Python 5.3.1) все работает.